# API Google maps para desktop, e sem conexão com a internet

Tags: c++, google-maps, qt

Alguém conhece uma maneira de se utilizar a `API` do Google Maps para Desktop sem conexão com a internet?

Preciso plotar no mapa alguns itens, mas não é sempre que o usuário terá acesso a Internet para carregar os mapas. Em mobile isso é possível, porém, gostaria de saber se tem algo para Desktop.

Uso `C++` junto com o qt creator, com o componente `QWebView`.